# Dimension subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, least-squares

Matrix $B= \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 3 & 6\\ 1 & 2 & 5
\end{bmatrix}$. Find
 $Y^*$ s.t.

$$\underset{{x \in Y^*,\|x\|_2 =1}}  \min  \|Bx\|_2=\underset{{\dim Y=2, x \in Y},}  \max \underset{{\|x\|_2 =1}}  \min \|Bx\|_2.$$
I appreciate some solutions or relevant notes.

Comment: Is the $\max$ on the right hand side a maximum over possible subspaces $S$?

Comment: @πr8 I think it should be that minimum over possible $S$ on the right hand side.